# How to implement different operations on a React App Calculator without hooks

Tags: reactjs, calculator

I am getting stuck on how to implement different method and condition for the calculator to add, multiply ,divide and substract.
my code can only display every button value(name) on the input text if it's pressed.
i created the `state` in the constructor call `result` which display `value(name) of the button` in the `input text` so its display the value of the button in the input text  but setting the result in a new state using `this.setState({result: this.state.result})` and for the calculator to accepted more then one value i had to `concatinate` the actual `state` + an `event.target.value`.
Now my getting stuck of how to implement method for this calculator to work.

```
import React,{Component} from "react";


 class DesignedCalc extends Component{
     constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
      result: "",       
      } 

      // bind all the event
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      this.handleClear = this.handleClear.bind(this);
      this.handleCalculate= this.handleCalculate.bind(this);
    } // end of constructor  

    
    //handleClick function that display value(name) of the button in the input Text.
      handleClick(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      let initialValue = this.state.result
      let addValue = event.target.name;
      this.setState({
        result :  initialValue+addValue 
      })  
    }
  
    //handleClear function clear the input form 
    handleClear(event){
      this.setState({
        result:"",
      })
      event.preventDefault()
    };
    
   
   // handleCalculate should give the output; final result of an arithmetic operation   
   handleCalculate(event){
     this.setState({
       result:"help me for the arithmetic logic"????
     })
    event.preventDefault();
  }// end of handleCalculate function

  
  
   render(){
       return(
           <div>
             
          <div className="container">
            <form>
        <div className="header">Calculator</div>
               <input type="text" className="result"  value={this.state.result}  readOnly={true}/> 
        <table>
            <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><button name="7"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick}>7</button> </td>
            <td><button name="8"  className="global"  onClick={this.handleClick}>8</button> </td>
            <td><button name="9"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick}>9</button> </td>
            <td><button name="/"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick}>/</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><button name="4"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick}>4</button> </td>
            <td><button name="5"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick}>3</button></td>
            <td><button name="6"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick}>2</button></td>
            <td><button name="*"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick}>X</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><button name="1"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick} >1</button></td>
            <td><button name="2" className="global" onClick={this.handleClick} >2</button></td>
            <td><button name="3"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick} >3</button></td>
            <td><button name="-"  className="global" onClick={this.handleClick} >-</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="3"><button name="0" className="global grey" onClick={this.handleClick} >0</button></td>
            
            <td rowSpan="3"><button name="+" className="global plus"  onClick={this.handleClick}> +</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><button name="Del" className="global red white-text" onClick={this.handleClear} >Clear</button></td>
            <td colSpan="2"><button name="=" className="global green white-text"  onClick={this.handleCalculate} >=</button></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
        
           </div>
       )
   }
 }

export default DesignedCalc
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow. you can use the eval function which basically evaluate the string expression but I would suggest to validate the input before passing to eval.

```
this.setState({
  result: eval(this.state.result)
});
```